# How to import third lib in rnplay(React Native Playground)?

Tags: react-native

I found some question existed in `react-native-gallery`, and I want to test it in `rnplay`, but how to import `react-native-gallery` in `rnplay`? Directly import it will encounter error 'unable to resolve module react-native-gallery '.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible atm. according to their [about page](https://rnplay.org/about):

> **You may only use native modules from React Native itself, or those we include 
>   in our build.**
>
> Your app may not work if it uses features not available in our
>   supported React Native versions.
>
> Your app can't yet refer to locally stored assets, since we have no
>   way to package those at runtime.